# Windows 2008 R2 - 8000FFFF Windows Update error

Tags: windows-update

does anyone know how to fix Windows Update when I'm getting 8000FFFF error?

I've already tried Step 1,2,3 from this site:

[Vista update error](http://www.tomstricks.com/how-to-fix-windows-vista-update-error-code8000ffff-cannot-update-the-computer/)

when I tried to update Windows Update Agent installer returned 8000FFFF error too.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a read of [Windows Update fails with 8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)](http://blogs.technet.com/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/07/03/windows-update-fails-with-8000ffff-e-unexpected.aspx) the gist of which is:

> Quick Solution:  Check the permissions
>   on  the root of C: and ensure that
>   BUILTIN\Users have Read access.

Have a look at the WindowsUpdate.log in your Windows directory and the Application Event logs to confirm that you are getting the same errors as in the [Brad Rutkowski's Blog entry](http://blogs.technet.com/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/07/03/windows-update-fails-with-8000ffff-e-unexpected.aspx).

Comment: that works for me too

Comment: How come I dont see this Builtin\users group? Where to find this one?

Comment: Is this Builtin\users local group or domain group?

Comment: BUILTIN\Users is a Windows Operating System local group. See https://serverfault.com/questions/376703/definition-of-builtin-users for more information.