# Definition of BUILTIN\Users?

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-authentication

For a server on a Windows Domain, what is the membership of "BUILTIN\Users" exactly?

(I figure this has an obvious answer, but googling hasn't given me any clear definitions)

Comment: If you could expand your question a bit, what exactly are you not clear about?

Comment: @jscott - I just couldn't find a definition for it! But your answer is ideal, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Microsoft KB 243330 [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330)

> SID: S-1-5-32-545
>
> Name: Users
>
> Description: A built-in group. After the initial installation of the operating system, the only member is the Authenticated Users group. When a computer joins a domain, the Domain Users group is added to the Users group on the computer.

When you install a Windows Server, the only member of the local `Users` group is local group `Authenticated Users`.  Upon joining the server to your domain, the domain group `EXAMPLE\Domain Users` would be added to `Users`.